# Why is a Postgres process with a strange name consuming a lot of CPU?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a Postgres cluster v14 on AWS Ubuntu server.
Recently, the master node had a strange process that take up almost 50% of CPU as the following snapshot when I run `top -i` on ubuntu

[image]

when I kill this process, the CPU usage drop but after that it appeared again with a different COMMAND (looks like it's a random id).
I did query the `pg_stat_activity` but didn't see any strange query, the system is under normal or low load.
The replica node (stream replication) is normal and only 3% CPU usage.
Do you have any suggestion for this?
Thank you.

Comment: You have been hacked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034/user-postgres-launches-process-that-takes-all-cpus-100-usage

Comment: yeah, just changed my server and added more layers of security, looks like it's gone. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name